# How do I transfer newly added rows in an SQL Server table to an identical MySQL table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, xampp

Basically, I have two identical tables in SQL Server and MySQL. I want to use PHP in such a way that I'll only have to manually insert new values in one of them. I want to make a PHP code where the newly inserted values in the SQL Server table will also be inserted in its identical counterpart in MySQL with the press of a button.

For example, I have a table named "Customers" in both SQL Server and MySQL with the rows "ID (auto incremented)", Name, and Address. I insert new values into those columns in SQL Server. How do I make it so that I'll only have to press a button made in PHP so that I won't have to do the whole "insert into" process again in MySQL?

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to new information given in the comments, I'm changing my answer and adjusting the code.

Code example:

```
<?php
 $serverName = "server"; //serverName\instanceName
 $connectionInfo_mssql = array("Database"=>"DB", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password","CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
 $conn_mssql = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo_bi);
 $conn_mysql = new mysqli("server", "username", "password", "db");

//SELECT FROM MS SQL DB
$mssql_array = array();
$ms_sql = "SELECT column_names FROM db_table";
$mssql_query = sqlsrv_query($conn_mssql , $ms_sql);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($mssql_query) {
  $mssql_array[] = array('name' => $row['name'],
                         'adress' => $row['adress']);
}

foreach($mssql_array as $key => $value) {

   //SELECT FROM MySQL DB
   $my_sql = "SELECT column_names FROM db_table WHERE name = '".$value['name']."' AND adress = '".$value['adress']."'";
   $mysql_query = mysqli_query($conn_mysql , $my_sql);
   $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($mysql_query);

   if ($num_rows == 0) {
     //Insert in MySQL DB
     $sql = "INSERT INTO db_table (db_columns) VALUES (variables_from_array)";
     $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn_mysql, $sql);
   } else {
     //There is a record in DB, and maybe you want to update it. If not, then lose this else part.
   }

}

echo 'Table Customers from MS SQL DB and table Customers from MySQL DB are now synced!';

?>
```

Comment: I see, this works well if I'm going to insert values to both tables at the same time.

But what if what I'm trying to do is simply carry over changes I've made from one table to another? For example, again, the "Customers" table in both SQL Server and MySQL. Both have similar columns, but the table in SQL Server has, say, 50 more rows than the one in MySQL. How do I get this rows to be added to the MySQL table  using PHP?

Comment: OK, so you don't want to do it at the moment a user clicks on a button, but transfer specific columns for each record at some later stage without user interaction? Am I getting it right?

Comment: No, sorry, but I don't think that's it either. What I'm trying to say is what if the two tables have different amount of records in them. For example, both SQL Server and MySQL have the "Customers" table in them with the same columns, but the Customers table in SQL server has 50 more records than its MySQL counterpart. What I want to do is to make a PHP code where it can detect that the MySQL Customers table is lacking 50 records, and with the press of a button, it takes the extra 50 records from the SQL server Customers table and adds it into MySQL. Sorry if I'm not making any sense

Comment: OK, so you want to compare both DB and sync the difference between them?

Comment: yes that's exactly it! i want to do just that, and make them similar with a button press.

Comment: OK, I understand now. There are a couple of ways to do it. 1) From your primary DB (I guess MSSQL) you can select all values and then truncate table on your secondary DB (I guess MySQL) and insert everything from primary DB. 2) Select everything from primary DB and select everything from secondary DB and insert only differences. 3) Change the logic on the initial insert, so you insert in both DB's at the same time. Any of these look OK for you so that we can continue from that point?

Comment: #2 seems to be the best option for what I'm trying to do

Comment: OK, is there any unique fields that are same in both DB's? Not ID which is autoincrementing.

Comment: I tagged the Name column as Unique when I created the table. Also why can't use the autoincrementing field?

Comment: I edited my post, so you cant take a look and try that example, only you need to adjust all DB column names and any typos I did. It's not optimized in the best way, but it will do what you need and maybe give you an idea of how to improve. Autoincrement is not a good idea in your case, because record 15 in MSSQL probably is not the same as record 15 in MySQL. But if the name is unique then that's the way to go.

Comment: @YMSmash There is no button in programming world that'll do this job for you. You need programming logic behind that button. Why is it necessary to have this button?